Covering Test Class for TriggerHandler on QuoteLine with Renewal Quote Logic in Salesforce CPQ
I created a TriggerHandler on QuoteLine with logic handling renewal quotes and associated objects, which works as expected. However, covering this functionality in a test class is posing a challenge.
In the test class setup, FYI the documented steps for renewal quote creation, as outlined here in Salesforce CPQ help by setting up the necessary test records (Account, Product, Opportunity, PricebookEntry, etc.).
The primary issue is with creating a Contract during the testSetup. Salesforce CPQ takes additional processing time to complete the Contract creation, causing errors in the main test method due to the absence of the Contract record, specifically throwing List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Any insights or methods to ensure the Contract is created before proceeding in the main test would be appreciated.
Code:
@IsTest public class QuoteLineTriggerHandlerTest {

@testSetup static void generateTestData(){
    blng__BillingRule__c billingRuleInstance = new blng__BillingRule__c(
        blng__Active__c = true, 
        blng__GenerateInvoices__c = 'Yes', 
        blng__InitialBillingTrigger__c = 'Order Product Activation Date',
        blng__PartialPeriodTreatment__c = 'Separate');
    insert billingRuleInstance;
    System.debug('##billingRuleInstance: ' + billingRuleInstance);
    
    blng__RevenueRecognitionRule__c revenueRecRule = new blng__RevenueRecognitionRule__c();
    revenueRecRule.blng__Active__c = true;
    revenueRecRule.blng__CreateRevenueSchedule__c = 'Yes';
    insert revenueRecRule;
    System.debug('##revenueRecRule: ' +revenueRecRule );
    
    blng__TaxRule__c taxRuleInstance = new blng__TaxRule__c(
        blng__Active__c = true, 
        Name = 'Default Tax',
        blng__TaxableYesNo__c = 'No'
    );
    insert taxRuleInstance;
    System.debug('##taxRuleInstance: ' + taxRuleInstance);
    
    
    Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
    
    Product2 prod = new Product2(
        Name = 'Test Product',
        isActive = true,
        ProductCode = '123',
        blng__BillingRule__c = billingRuleInstance.Id,
        blng__RevenueRecognitionRule__c = revenueRecRule.Id,
        blng__TaxRule__c = taxRuleInstance.Id,                 
        SBQQ__BillingType__c = 'Advance',
        SBQQ__ChargeType__c = 'Recurring',
        SBQQ__BillingFrequency__c = 'Monthly',
        SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c  = 12,
        SBQQ__SubscriptionPricing__c = 'Fixed Price',
        SBQQ__DefaultQuantity__c = 1.0,
        SBQQ__PricingMethod__c = 'List'
    );
    insert prod;
    System.debug('##prod:' + prod);
    
    PricebookEntry pe = new PricebookEntry(
        UnitPrice = 100, 
        Product2Id = prod.Id,
        Pricebook2Id = pricebookId,
        isActive = true
    );
    insert pe;
    System.debug('##pe:' + pe );
    
    Account testAccount = new Account(
        Name = 'Test',
        CurrencyIsoCode = 'NOK',
        StormGeo_Company__c = legalEntity.Id,
        Type = 'Client',
        Red_Flag_Check_Status__c = 'Approved',
        SBQQ__RenewalModel__c = 'Contract Based'
    );
    insert testAccount;
    System.debug('##testAccount :'+ testAccount);
    
    RecordType oppRecordtype = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name ='RT Opportunity'] ;
    Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity(
        Name = 'Test Opp',
        CloseDate = System.today().addYears(2),
        Amount = 1000,
        RecordTypeId = oppRecordtype.Id,
        PriceBook2Id = pricebookId,
        Billing_Type__c = 'Advance',
        AccountId = testAccount.Id,
        StageName = 'Closed-Won',
        Product_Names__c  = 'P1',
        Type_of_sale__c = 'New business',
        Opportunity_Type__c = 'New',
        New_Client__c = 'Yes',
        CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD',
    );
    insert testOpp;
    System.debug('##testOpp :' + testOpp );
    
    SBQQ__Quote__c quote = new SBQQ__Quote__c(
        SBQQ__Status__c = 'Draft',
        SBQQ__StartDate__c = System.today(),
        SBQQ__Account__c = testAccount.Id,
        SBQQ__Opportunity2__c = testOpp.Id,
        SBQQ__PricebookId__c = pricebookId,
        SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c = 12,
        SBQQ__Type__c = 'Quote',
        Invoice_Term__c = 'Monthly',
        CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD',
        SBQQ__Primary__c = true
    );
    insert quote;
    System.debug('##quote:' + quote);
    
    SBQQ__QuoteLineGroup__c quoteLineGroup = new SBQQ__QuoteLineGroup__c(
        Name = 'Test QLG',
        SBQQ__Quote__c = quote.Id
    );
    insert quoteLineGroup;
    System.debug('##quoteLineGroup: ' + quoteLineGroup );
    
    SBQQ__QuoteLine__c ql1 = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c(
        SBQQ__Quote__c = quote.Id,
        SBQQ__Product__c = prod.Id,
        SBQQ__PricebookEntryId__c = pe.Id,
        SBQQ__Quantity__c = 1,
        SBQQ__StartDate__c = System.today(),
        SBQQ__EndDate__c = System.today().addmonths(3),
        SBQQ__NetPrice__c = 1000,
        Unit__c = 'Month',
        SBQQ__Group__c = quoteLineGroup.Id
    );
    insert ql1;
    System.debug('##ql1:' + ql1 );
    
    //create contract via order
    testOpp.SBQQ__Ordered__c = true;
    Order order = [SELECT Id,status FROM Order WHERE OpportunityId =:testOpp.Id ];
    Order.status = 'Activated';
    update order;
    
    testOpp.SBQQ__Contracted__c = true;
    update testOpp;
    Contract contract = [SELECT Id,SBQQ__RenewalQuoted__c FROM Contract WHERE SBQQ__Opportunity__c =:testOpp.Id LIMIT 1 ];
    System.debug('## contract:' + contract );

}
@IsTest static void testAfterInsertHandler(){
    Opportunity testOpp = [SELECT Id,StageName,SBQQ__Contracted__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Name = 'Test Opp' LIMIT 1];
    Test.startTest();
    Contract contract = [SELECT Id,SBQQ__RenewalForecast__c,SBQQ__RenewalQuoted__c FROM Contract WHERE SBQQ__Opportunity__c =:testOpp.Id LIMIT 1 ];
    
    contract.SBQQ__RenewalQuoted__c = true;
    update contract;
    Test.stopTest();
}

}

refactor your code to use a selector layer for querying Contract, then at testmethod time you can dependency inject a mock selector that returns Contract SObjects. This way you avoid the DML issue
